# Does an immutable texture need a GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL?

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-4

When allocating textures using `glTexImage*` functions, I know that I need to set `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL)` to a reasonable value and specify all the levels up to that value, [as described here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture).

I didn't expect for this to be necessary in case of `glTexStorage*` functions too, since they accept the number of layers as a parameter and allocate memory for that number of layers up-front. Still, I noticed I couldn't sample an immutable texture defined this way - until I called `glGenerateMipmap` or specified `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` to `levels-1`.

I didn't find any official reason why it should be necessary and I expected immutable texture's parameters to be, well, immutable (and well-initialized). Can somebody confirm if (and why) this behaviour is correct? Or is it an AMD driver bug perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I got that:

The parameter `levels` of `glTexStorage` is indeed stored in the texture object, but as `GL_TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_LEVELS`, not as `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL`, as I thought.

The parameter `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` hence remains at the default large value. *(It's possible to change it manually: the immutable flag of texture object only relates to the texture buffer and its format, but not buffer data or parameters).*

The texture immutability should affect LOD calculation in the following way according to the spec:

> if TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_FORMAT is TRUE, then level<sub>base</sub> is clamped
>   to the range [0; level<sub>immut</sub> - 1]

So leaving `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` intact (= 1000) for an immutable texture shall have the same effect as setting it to `levels-1`.

Verdict: driver bug; the driver apparently omits this clamping step.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that I need to set glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL) to a reasonable value and specify all the levels up to that value, as described here.

Well, you don't have to. The default value for GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL is 1000 and hence larger than any image pyramid you'll every reasonably use.

> Still, I noticed I couldn't sample an immutable texture defined this way - until I called glGenerateMipmap or specified GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL to levels-1.

Yes, that's because image storage is independent of image sampling. The value of GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL is a parameter that affects image access at sampling time (you could set it into a Sampler Object as well) that's independent of the actual texture image storage. You can change the range of used image pyramid levels also *after* image specification, if you want to select only a subrange of images used during rendering, or only upload images into a subset of the allocated image pyramid.

*EDIT reworded for clarification*

Comment: I kind of suspected this, but state tables list `TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL` and `TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` as texture object state (while sampler object state has `TEXTURE_MIN_LOD` and `TEXTURE_MAX_LOD`). Can you confirm?

Comment: @Kos: Texture objects have TEXTURE_MIN_LOD and TEXTURE_MAX_LOD as well (just look into the OpenGL-2 spec, which didn't have sampler objects yet). Also remember that while the size of a texture image initialized with glTexStorage can not be changed the individual sub images can be changed at any time. So it's perfectly possible to replace a part of the image pyramid and set the base level and max level to the range of the images actually uploaded into the texture storage.

Comment: Yes, my point was that GL_TEXTURE_BASE/MAX_LEVEL might not be a sampling parameter since it's absent in sampler objects, unlike LOD params.